# Texto pré inserido do banco

Tags: flutter, dart

No meu app seria interessante este texto vir do banco não em formado de `placeholder` mas em um texto aonde ele pudesse alterar apenas uma virgula se quisesse, mas não consigo achar uma forma de fazer isso pois andei lendo a documentação do flutter e não achei nada que ajudasse nesse quesito.

```
class CommentStyle extends StatelessWidget {


  //Parametros que precisam ser passados para o CommentStyle
  const CommentStyle(this.index, this.model, {this.comentario});
  final int index;
  final UserModel model;
  final String comentario;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(89.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: StyleTextTitle("Perfil do contato"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_solid),
                      StyleTextTitle("Nome:"),
                      StyleTextInfo(model.contactsList[index]["fullname"]),
                    ],
                  ),

                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.mail),
                      StyleTextTitle("E-mail:"),
                      StyleTextInfo(model.contactsList[index]["email"]),
                    ],
                  ),

                  //Titulo acima do TextField.
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.pen),
                      StyleTextTitle("Comentário: "),
                    ],
                  ),
                 //Aqui que eu quero retornar o texto editavel
                  CupertinoTextField(
                    controller: controllerComent,
                    maxLines: 6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    placeholder: model.contactsList[index]["comentario"],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 255,
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Alimente o `controllerComent` com os dados do banco no `initState`( Se estiver usando um StatefullWidget) ou antes do `return` dentro do método `Build` (Caso esteja utilizando StatelessWidget). Assim que tiver um tempo, criarei uma resposta mais detalhada.

Comment: Obrigado, andei testando aqui e não consegui. Seu exemplo seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: O parametro que ele precisa receber é `model.contactsList[index]["id"]` porem so é possível pegar esses parâmetros dentro do meu widget `StateLess` que dentro dele passo os parâmetros que vao puxar do banco mas se coloco o controller dentro dele, acusa como se fosse um parâmetro necessário também e é ai que eu travo.

Comment: Nesse caso então, coloque o código completo de onde vai ser utilizado esse `TextField`, fornecer um exemplo mais completo ajuda a gente te ajudar hahaha

Comment: Pronto, adicionei rsrs

Comment: Vi que você abriu uma outra pergunta no SOP, [essa aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427122/pegar-dados-do-banco)... Se a dúvida principal desta pergunta aqui já foi sanada, favor marcar uma das respostas como ACEITA!

Comment: Acabei esquecendo de marcar. Obrigado por lembrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha mesmo você fornecendo o exemplo completo ainda faltou a criação do `TextController`, mas vamos lá, vou dar um exemplo e você ajusta a sua necessidade.

```
class CommentStyle extends StatelessWidget {


  //Parametros que precisam ser passados para o CommentStyle
  const CommentStyle(this.index, this.model, {this.comentario});
  final int index;
  final UserModel model;
  final String comentario;
  TextController controllerComent = TextController();    

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controllerComent.Text = "Texto que veio do banco";
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(89.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: StyleTextTitle("Perfil do contato"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_solid),
                      StyleTextTitle("Nome:"),
                      StyleTextInfo(model.contactsList[index]["fullname"]),
                    ],
                  ),

                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.mail),
                      StyleTextTitle("E-mail:"),
                      StyleTextInfo(model.contactsList[index]["email"]),
                    ],
                  ),

                  //Titulo acima do TextField.
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.pen),
                      StyleTextTitle("Comentário: "),
                    ],
                  ),
                 //Aqui que eu quero retornar o texto editavel
                  CupertinoTextField(
                    controller: controllerComent,
                    maxLines: 6,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    placeholder: model.contactsList[index]["comentario"],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 255,
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Por se tratar de um `StatelessWidget` você pode alimentar seu controller diretamente no `Build`.

Desta forma você terá a variável alimentada no momento que a tela for criada, já com os dados do banco e depois poderá utilizar ela novamente para recuperar o texto editado.

Comment: Não coloquei  o resto do código pois é somente a criação da tela como: app bar e chamando o StateLess dentro da Scaffold então não vi muita necessidade, porém da forma que você colocou funcionou aqui, exceto, pelo controller não poder ser declarado ali. O unico problema desta forma que você passou é que não fica possivel editar o texto dentro do TextField mas não deve ser nada muito dificil de resolver e mais uma vez muito Obrigado por sua ajuda.

Comment: Por nada! Esqueci de inicializar o `TextController` mas já modifiquei em minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você não colocou o código completo, aí fica difícil adivinhar de onde vêm as coisas, como o seu `controllerComent` por exemplo.

O erro está nele, você tem que criá-lo passando por parâmetro o texto que você quer que seja preenchido inicialmente o `CupertinoTextField`. Mude o seu trecho de código para isso:

```dart
CupertinoTextField(
  controller: TextEditingController(text: model.contactsList[index]["comentario"]),
  maxLines: 6,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  maxLength: 255,
),
```

E você já vai ver o texto apresentado no `TextField`. Agora, você tem que ver as implicações com o controller sendo criado diretamente aí, provavelmente não seja a melhor opção para você criá-lo nesse momento. Mas como eu não sei onde você está criando ele, fica contigo essa tarefa.